# Calculate the number of records for each date between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have to create a query to return results for a multi-axis chart.  I need to count the number of Ids created for each date between 2 dates.  I tried this:

```
 DECLARE @StartDate datetime2(7) = '11/1/2020',
         @EndDate datetime2(7) = '2/22/2021'

 ;WITH Date_Range_T(d_range) AS 
     (
       SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate) - @StartDate, 0) 
       UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) 
       FROM Date_Range_T 
       WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) < @EndDate
     )

  SELECT d_range, COUNT(Id) as Total 
  FROM Date_Range_T 
       LEFT JOIN [tbl_Support_Requests] on ([tbl_Support_Requests].CreatedDate Between @StartDate AND @EndDate) 
  GROUP BY d_range ORDER BY d_range ASC
```

Of course, the problem is with the `;WITH` which returns the error

> Operand type clash: datetime2 is incompatible with int.

The above works if I give it a specific number of days from the current date like:

```
 ;WITH Date_Range_T(d_range) AS 
 (
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0) 
   UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) 
   FROM Date_Range_T 
   WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) < GETDATE()
 )
```

Which returns:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to substitute the date range.

Comment: FYI `;WITH` is actually `WITH` (and called a CTE - Common Table Expression). The semi-colon is a statement terminator, so belongs with the previous statement. And as per the SQL Server guidelines all statements should now be semi-colon terminated.

Comment: I need a total records for each day between the two dates.  My result set should be something like 11/1/2020 - 2, 11/2/2020- 5, 11/3/2020 - 8.

Comment: just like GetDate()-6 gives me all of the days between today and 6 days ago, I am trying to figure out how to substitute startdate and enddate to get all the dates in between those dates.

Comment: **Dates are not numbers**, even if historically SQL Server let you do that, it comes back to bite you. Why do this `DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 6, 0)` when you can do the much clearer `DATEADD(DAY, -6, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel - there are many examples of recursive CTE calendar tables out there, similar to below.

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '01-Nov-2020', @EndDate date = '22-Feb-2021';

WITH Date_Range_T (d_range) AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS d_range
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) 
    FROM Date_Range_T 
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, d_range) < @EndDate
)
SELECT d_range, COUNT(Id) AS Total 
FROM Date_Range_T 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Support_Requests R ON R.CreatedDate = d_range
GROUP BY d_range
ORDER BY d_range ASC
-- Set to the max number of days you require
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366);
```

Comments:

- Why use a `datetime2` for a `date`?
- Do you definitely want `<` the end date or `<=`?
- Are you familiar with how `between` works - its not always intuitive.
- Alias all tables for better readability.
- Semi-colon terminate all statements.
- Consistent casing makes the query easier to read.
- Use an unambiguous date format for date strings.

Comment: all of the dates in the database are datetime2  I am not going to keep it like that for the query.  In order to get your answer to work properly, I had to change the join to "LEFT JOIN tbl_Support_Requests R on R.CreatedDate = d_range" .  The way it is currently in your response returns the overall count (46) for every day instead of the specific number for each.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff of course - fixed now - I was just solving the posted error - as you didn't provide any sample data I wasn't able to test the entire query.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: use a tally table/function, not a slow rCTE

Answer (score 2):

Improving on [Dale K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66324614/14868997), I suggest you use a tally table or function, as this is usually more performant.

I have used Itzik Ben-Gan's [well-known one](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) below:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2020-11-01', @EndDate date = '2021-02-22';

  WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L2 )
    Date_Range_T (d_range) AS (
      SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
          DATEADD(day, rownum - 1, @StartDate) AS d_range,
          DATEADD(day, rownum, @StartDate) AS d_rangeNext
      FROM Nums
    )
SELECT d_range, COUNT(Id) AS Total 
FROM Date_Range_T 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Support_Requests R
    ON R.CreatedDate >= T.d_range AND R.CreatedDate < T.d_rangeNext
GROUP BY d_range
ORDER BY d_range ASC
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitely have to read up on this because VALUES(1), (1), etc. make no sense at all.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Basically, `L0,L1,L2` are just row generators cross-joined together, we ignore the actual values and use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate `12,3,4,5,6...` Then we generate the dates based off that

Comment: Yep, still makes no sense. selecting 1 from 16 1's.  Why 16?  I'm going to need to read for this to make sense.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can't have a no-column `select` so need at least one dummy column. As I said: select 16 values, cross join itself, cross join that again, ignore the actual values and instead just calculate a rownumber. So we have a single column from 1 to 65536 (you can cross join again if you need more). Then we calculate the dates off that.

Comment: something I just discovered, there is something wrong here as neither your solution nor Dale K's provide a total for ANY dates in 2021.  It gives zeros as the total for any date in 2021.  I am using values DECLARE StartDate date = '2020-11-02', EndDate date = '2021-02-13';  Any ideas what might cause such a thing?

Comment: Not sure, but looking at it: do the dates you are joining to have time parts to them for example `11:00` or `17:53:27`?

Comment: OK given you the solution for that. The best way is not to convert the other side to `date` but to do a half-open range check `>= AND <` so I've added an extra column in the CTE that gets the beginning of the next day