# Is there a way to count number of each days in sql

Tags: sql-server, date

```
declare @date1 as date 2021-02-01
declare @date1 as date 2021-02-20
```

Here I want to get the number of each days occurred between the given date. The result should display the number of each days occurred

```
Monday 3
Tuesday 3
Wednesday 3
Thursday 3
Friday 3
Saturday 3
Sunday 2
```

Comment: I have not tried anything, I don't exactly know how to write its code

Comment: Hi Dale,I Tried it by myself and i got the solution using the code below, I think its naive but it works, can you please take a loot in to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '1/1/2021'
SET @EndDate = '1/31/2021'

select 
    datediff(dd, -7, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -6, @StartDate)/7 AS MON,
    datediff(dd, -6, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -5, @StartDate)/7 AS TUE,
    datediff(dd, -5, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -4, @StartDate)/7 AS WED,
    datediff(dd, -4, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -3, @StartDate)/7 AS THU,
    datediff(dd, -3, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -2, @StartDate)/7 AS FRI,
    datediff(dd, -2, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, -1, @StartDate)/7 AS SAT,
    datediff(dd, -1, @EndDate)/7-datediff(dd, 0, @StartDate)/7   AS SUN
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried in in this way

```
declare @date1 as date = '2021-02-01'
declare @date2 as date= '2021-02-23'
drop table #days
create table #days
(
daynames varchar(50)
)

while (@date1<=@date2)
begin
insert into #days
values(datename(dw,@date1));
set @date1=dateadd(d,1,@date1)
end
select tb1.daynames,max(tb1.count) as 'visit count' from  (select  
daynames,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by daynames order by daynames) as count
from #days) as tb1
group by tb1.daynames
```

Comment: Well done for having a go! OK I suggest you google calendar table or tally table. Here is an example, look at Charlieface's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324479/calculate-the-number-of-records-for-each-date-between-2-dates/66324614#66324614