# SSRS Report/SQL Server: Display distinct column values even if there is no data on particular dates

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I want to solve this problem for SSRS reports. I want to display all dates between @startdate and @enddate. I have accomplished this part. Next,I want to display distinct column values (for column named "name") for dates for which data doesn't exist. (i.e. aa,bb for all dates that I am generating)

What I am getting :

| Date | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00:00 | no data | no data |
| 02/01/2021 00:00:00 | no data | no data |
| 03/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | 23 |
| 03/01/2021 00:01:00 | bb | 32 |
| 04/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | 54 |
| 04/01/2021 00:01:00 | bb | 90 |

What I want :

| Date | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | no data |
| 01/01/2021 00:00:00 | bb | no data |
| 02/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | no data |
| 02/01/2021 00:00:00 | bb | no data |
| 03/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | 23 |
| 03/01/2021 00:01:00 | bb | 32 |
| 04/01/2021 00:00:00 | aa | 54 |
| 04/01/2021 00:01:00 | bb | 90 |

Here is my attempt:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DateTime
DECLARE @ENDDATE DateTime
SET @STARTDATE = '2021-01-01'
SET @ENDDATE = '2021-01-04'
;with dates ([Date]) as (
    Select convert(date,@STARTDate) as [Date] 
    union all 
    Select dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
    from dates
    where [Date] <= @ENDDATE 
)

select 
isnull(n.Created_Date,d.date) Date,
isnull(n.[NAME],'No Data') [NAME],
isnull(n.[VALUE],'No Data') [VALUE]
from dates d
left join Table_A n on convert(varchar, n.Created_Date, 101) = d.Date
where

([Created_Date] between (@StartDate) and (@EndDate) or
[Date] between (@StartDate-1) and (@EndDate) )
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324479/calculate-the-number-of-records-for-each-date-between-2-dates/66336913#66336913 interesting. By the way: you really shouldn't compare dates that way. If you want to strip out the time part, the best way is to add a `nextDay` column to the CTE and  `n.Created_Date >= d.Date AND n.Created_Date < d.nextDay`. Also you shouldn't use `date-1` use `dateadd(day, -1...` instead

Comment: I will keep it in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call this pattern the "cross-join, left-join".  You use a cross join to create the matrix of all possible values, and then a left join to fill in the available values.

So you'll need a table of all the possible `Names` to cross-join.  eg

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DateTime
DECLARE @ENDDATE DateTime
SET @STARTDATE = '2021-01-01'
SET @ENDDATE = '2021-01-04'
;with dates ([Date]) as (
    Select convert(date,@STARTDate) as [Date] 
    union all 
    Select dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
    from dates
    where [Date] <= @ENDDATE 
), names as
(
  select distinct Name 
  from Table_A
)
select 
isnull(n.Created_Date,d.date) Date,
names.Name [NAME],
isnull(n.[VALUE],'No Data') [VALUE]
from dates
cross join names
left join Table_A n 
  on n.Created_Date = dates.Date
  and n.Name = names.Name
where dates.[Date] between dateadd(day,-1,@StartDate) and @EndDate 
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```