# Loop through each row in a table for a given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing dates

```
declare @x date ='01-jan-2021'
declare @y date ='31-jan-2021'
create table hdate( a date)
 
while @x <= @y
begin
    insert into hdate(a) values( @x)
    set @x = dateadd(day,1,@x)
end
```

How can I loop through each record?

e.g

```
declare @start_no int =1
declare @end_no int
select @end_no = count(*) from hdate where a between '05-jan-2021 and '10-jan-2020'
while @start_no <= @end_no
begin
    select a from hdate
    set @start_no = @start_no+1

    --how do I get next record?
end
```

Expected result is

```
a
05-jan-2021
06-jan-2021
07-jan-2021
08-jan-2021
09-jan-2021
10-jan-2021
```

I want to use while loop. Please help

Comment: Why do you want to use a while loop? SQL is optimised for set based operations.

Comment: need to get balances for these dates sir Jim has shown me how to do it Thanks Sir

Comment: But why a loop rather than a CTE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the number of records for each date between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324479/calculate-the-number-of-records-for-each-date-between-2-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim showed how you can get the desired result using a loop but pointed out that loops are not the way to go. In SQL Server, the *correct* way to do this would be to use a numbers table or function, such as [fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally).

```
declare @x date ='01-jan-2021'
declare @y date ='31-jan-2021'

SELECT SomeDate = DATEADD(DAY,f.N,@x) FROM dbo.fnTally(0,DATEDIFF(DAY,@x,@y)) AS f;
```

Returns:

```
SomeDate
----------
2021-01-01
2021-01-02
2021-01-03
...
2021-01-29
2021-01-30
2021-01-31
```

Much faster and efficient with much less code.

Comment: Alan.  I'm not sure if either of us answered his question, but many thanks for the fnTally reference. Finding nuggets like this is why I come back to answer questions from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to use loops, but I'm sure you have your reasons...

```
-- 
-- option 1
--
declare @x date ='01-jan-2021'
declare @y date ='31-jan-2021'
declare @hdate table ( a date)

while @x<=@y
begin
insert into @hdate(a) values( @x)
set @x=dateadd(day,1,@x)
end


declare @i date 
declare @j date
select top 1 @i =  a from @hdate order by a
while @i is not null
    begin
    select @j = @i, @i = null


    select top 1 @i = a from @hdate where a > @j order by a
    select @j,@i

end

go

-- 
-- option 2
--
declare @x date ='01-jan-2021'
declare @y date ='31-jan-2021'
declare @hdate table ( a date, rowNum int identity)

while @x<=@y
begin
insert into @hdate(a) values( @x)
set @x=dateadd(day,1,@x)
end

select * from @hdate


declare @i int = 1
declare @j int 
select @j =  max(rowNum) from @hdate
while @i <= @j
    begin
    select * from @hdate where rowNum = @i
    select @i = @i + 1

end

go
-- 
-- option 3 -- no loop
--
declare @x date ='01-jan-2021'
declare @y date ='31-jan-2021'
declare @hdate table ( a date)

while @x<=@y
begin
insert into @hdate(a) values( @x)
set @x=dateadd(day,1,@x)
end

select * from @hdate


declare @i date = '01-jan-2021'

select h1.a as prev, x.a as next 
from @hdate h1
outer apply ( select top 1 h2.a from @hdate h2 where h2.a > h1.a) x
where h1.a = @i
order by h1.a

go
```

Comment: thanks Jim Actually I have a table with dates but not incrimental as  i  have placed here Therefore I want to know how do i get next record when i incriment counter by 1

Comment: not sure I understand your comment.  Both option 1 and option 2 will not care if there are gaps in the dates.  They are relative ordering.  If you are looking for a simple prev/next, out apply is useful (see option 3).

Comment: yes i followed your direction and it is working sir

Answer (score 0):

You can create sequential values with [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions), which adds new item on each step of recursion. So there's no need to write imperative code for such tasks.

```
declare @x date = convert(date, '2021-01-01', 23);
declare @y date = convert(date, '2021-01-31', 23);

with a (dt) as (
  select @x
  where @x <= @y
  
  union all

  select dateadd(d, 1, dt)
  from a
  where dt < @y
)
insert into hdate(a)
select dt
from a
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=1b1cc364ca3b8768f3f118662c17aca7)*

Answer (score 0):

Given your dates are not sequential you can use:

```
declare @start_date datetime = '05-jan-2021'
declare @end_date datetime = '10-jan-2021'

declare @cdate datetime = @start_date

while (@cdate is not null or datediff(dd, @cdate, @end_date) >= 0)
begin

    select @cdate = min(a) from #hdate 
      where a between @cdate and @end_date

    if (@cdate is not null) 
    begin
        select a from #hdate
        where a = @cdate
    end

    select @cdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @cdate)

end
```