# Why cte for returning months doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to go through Common Table Expressions, and decided to write a cte that returns month names.

```
with cte_month(n, monthname)
as
(
    select 0, datename(m,0)
    union all
    select n+1,datename(m,n+1)
    from cte_month
    where n < 11
)
select monthname from cte_month;
```

The corresponding weekday cte works fine,

```
WITH cte_numbers(n, weekday) 
AS (
    SELECT 
        0, 
        DATENAME(DW, 0)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    
        n + 1, 
        DATENAME(DW, n + 1)
    FROM    
        cte_numbers
    WHERE n < 6
)
SELECT 
    weekday
FROM 
    cte_numbers;
```

but what is wrong with this month cte?

Comment: [`DateName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) takes a `date`, not an `int` as a parameter. You can see what is happening with `DateAdd( day, n + 1, 0 ) as TargetDate`.

Comment: By the way, you may find this interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/66336913/14868997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `DATENAME` is a date not an int, so create a date using the int value...

```
with cte_month(n, monthname)
as
(
    select 1, datename(m,0)
    union all
    select n+1,datename(m,DATEFROMPARTS(2021,n+1,1))
    from cte_month
    where n < 12
)
select * from cte_month;
```

Using `datename(m,0)` works in the initial `select` because it is the equivalent of `datename(m,cast(0 as datetime))` which will return "January" as the base datetime in SQL Server is 1900-01-01 (i.e. a January datetime).