# Add 48 hours to a date to create a new date, add 48 hours to new date and repeat until end date is reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 datetime stamps: Date of Admission, Date of Discharge, Date of Review.

There is only 1 admission date and 1 discharge date per patient but multiple Review dates in between the admission and discharge dates.

I am being asked to report whether or not a review was completed every 2 days from admission to discharge. There is a timestamp captured each time a review is completed and its stored in the Review Date column.

I understand that I can use the `dateadd` function to add 48 hours to the admit date but then I need to add 48 hours to that new date and keep doing this until discharge in order to capture each possible 48 hour interval in which a review should have been completed and I don't know how to do that.

I would then use the newly created timestamps of 48 hours intervals from admission, in order to see if a review was completed between each 48 hour interval from admit to discharge.

This is an example of what I have currently:

| PATIENT_VISIT_ID | ADMIT_DATE | DISCHARGE_DATE | REVIEW_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/5/2021 11:51 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/5/2021 11:51 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/9/2021 16:18 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/9/2021 16:19 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/9/2021 16:20 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/10/2021 10:38 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/11/2021 11:30 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/13/2021 15:30 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/13/2021 15:32 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/13/2021 15:33 |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/15/2021 13:14 |

This is what I am trying to do:

| PATIENT_VISIT_ID | ADMIT_DATE | DISCHARGE_DATE | 48 Hour Intervals from admit | Review completed within this particular 48 hour interval? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/2/2021 11:53 | No |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/4/2021 11:53 | No |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/6/2021 11:53 | Yes |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/8/2021 11:53 | No |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/10/2021 11:53 | Yes |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/12/2021 11:53 | Yes |
| 123 | 3/31/2021 11:53 | 4/15/2021 16:23 | 4/14/2021 11:53 | Yes |

Hope this makes sense. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You need a calendar table, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324479/calculate-the-number-of-records-for-each-date-between-2-dates/66336913#66336913

Comment: What happens when that 48 hour period includes the DST jump (either direction)?

Comment: SMor - all the timestamps are captured in localtime and account for DST

Comment: Gordon Linoff - thank you I was able to add the sample data and desired results to my question.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you just want to do this :

```
select
    PATIENT_VISIT_ID,
    ADMIT_DATE,
    DISCHARGE_DATE,
    REVIEW_DATE,
    DATEADD(hour, 48,ADMIT_DATE) as [48 Hour Intervals from admit],
    case when REVIEW_DATE <= DATEADD(hour, 48,ADMIT_DATE) then 'Yes'
    else 'No' end as  [Review completed within this particular 48 hour interval?]
from
    table t
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's actually a bit more than that. Adding 48hrs to the admit date is just the first step. What I'm having trouble with is figuring out how to keep adding 48hours until discharge. I included an example of what the output data should look like.