# How to define a view that will give zeros on days with no recording?

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple tables with a view that joins them

```
CREATE TABLE Valve (
  ValveID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  ValveName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ValveOwner varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ValveRecording (
  ValveID int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  Date date NOT NULL,
  Measure varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  Value numeric NOT NULL
)


ALTER VIEW ValveRecordingView
AS
SELECT
   v.ValveName,
   v.ValveOwner,
   vr.Measure,
   vr.Value
FROM Valve v
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValveRecording vr on v.ValveID = vr.ValveID
```

*Note above was just typed in - so may have errors.

The problem with the view is that if queried for a date range where no measurement was made,
there is no row present for the measure-value pair. I would like to
restate the view in a way that some value is returned for each date-measure-value tuples.
If one wasn't present then return a zero.

I think that it's possible, but the SQL is a bit beyond me.  I assume
that it involves a UNION ALL with a query that gets date-measure-value
tuples which aren't already present. Probably an ugly query but that's
okay.

Comment: You need to invest in making yourself a Calendar Table. Then you can `LEFT JOIN` from said table to your data and then a row will be returned for that date, regardless of if there is data in your table.

Comment: Couldn't I join with a "virtual" calendar table - in the form of a distinct date query on the ValveRecording table?

Comment: If the date doesn't exist in the table, that won't help you. Calendar tables are an invaluable resource, so creating one in your environment is always beneficial. Even if you don't have many uses for it right now, you'll quickly find you end up using it more and more as it makes some takes much easier.

Comment: Your issue though is your table doesn't contain a row for every date, so how do you envisage that working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the number of records for each date between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324479/calculate-the-number-of-records-for-each-date-between-2-dates) A good example of an on the fly date table, your query will look like this `select ... from Dates left join ValveRecordingView...`

Comment: Every date is present in the data table - just not for every valve

Comment: @Charlieface, My challenge is that I'm making a view not a query

Comment: A view though *is* just a query. You could create a view of your distinct dates or use a CTE in your query, although a permanent indexed calendar table would offer better performance; either way, start from that and `left-outer-join` to it.

Comment: If you need to use a CTE in a view, you can do it like this `CREATE VIEW SomeView AS WITH CTE AS (... ) SELECT...` Note that if you are creating this as a view, you **must not** use the recursive CTE option, as you cannot define `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` on a view. You must use the cross-join CTE.

Comment: @Charlieface, why a cross-join?

Comment: As I said, you cannot use `MAXRECURSION` in a view, it would have to be defined on every query that uses the view, which can get annoying. It's also less performant anyway. You may find [this article interesting](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge), it explains how the cross-join/row-number trick works